# How I use .Live() jQuery function with Jquery UI datepicker?

Tags: dom, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker (localized to spanish):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker(
        { dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo',
                'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre',
                'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr',
                'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago',
                'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var form = $(form);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Trabajo/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { dia: dateText },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#trabajos').replaceWith($('#trabajos', $(result)));
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

Its working perfectly, its updating the #trabajos div with the new info but the dom is not updated. I know that .live() is for that but, as jquery noobish, how I change this code to implement the live function?

Thank you.

PS: If there is a asp.net mvc guy, if my form is like:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("/Trabajo/", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "trabajos" }))
```

Why I have to manually update it on the success func?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    attachDatePicker();
});

function attachDatePicker() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var form = $(form);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Trabajo/',
                type: "POST",
                data: { dia: dateText },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#trabajos').replaceWith($('#trabajos', $(result)));
                    // reattach the datepicker if you updated 
                    // the corresponding DOM element
                    attachDatePicker();
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Remark: never hardcode urls in your javascript files as you did in the url property of your AJAX call. Always Url helpers. So instead of:

```
url: '/Trabajo/'
```

use:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Trabajo")'
                     ^         ^
                  action    controller
```

Comment: Thank you, but is not working, the page updates but the DOM doesn't, on the other hand, in the page now, I have to click many times on the right mouse button to show the context menu, weird.

Comment: @Jesus Rodriguez, what does `the page updates but the DOM doesn't` means? Are you getting a javascript error?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov the page show the changes but the DOM is not updated. An error, just this: "element.getAttribute is not a function" inside ajax unobstrusive.js.

Comment: @Jesus Rodriguez, is this something related to your `Ajax.BeginForm` helper? If so don't use `Ajax.BeginForm` as it might mess things up. Try using a normal `Html.BeginForm`.

Comment: I changed it but same thing. I think I need the live method of jquery for that but I dont know how to use it on my code.

Comment: @Jesus Rodriguez, `.live` method wouldn't apply to a datepicker. Please explain what happens in details. I don't understand what doesn't work and how your code look like.

Comment: I have just a datepicker and a div, when I click on the datepicker, the div update with new info, I Can see the info but the dom of the div is still the old DOM, so, when I click on the datepicked and the div update, I want the dom to be updated too.